# How to turn off assertion evaluation with no access to php.ini?

Tags: php

With access to php.ini one can turn off assertion evaluation with:

```
zend.assertions = -1
```

In shared hosting often one can only use ini_set:

```
ini_set('assert.active', '0');
```

But this setting does still evaluate the code in the assertions. In my understanding it does the same as *zend.assertions = 0*.

Can the effect of *zend.assertions = -1* be achieved when there is no possibility to edit php.ini?

Edit:

Based on the answer I'm adding this remark:

*ini_set('zend.assertions', ...)* is prevented by the hosting company.

Comment: I've deleted my answer, because you'd missed a crucial piece of information, which I had no way of guessing. So to clarify, your hosting company has put assertions into development mode, locked the setting, and you're looking for a way to bypass their restriction?

Comment: As for 'assert.active', I'm pretty sure that was just the setting from previous versions of PHP, and any references to it are out of date.

Comment: Yes, as a temporary measure while working on a legacy app. I'm introducing assertions (besides other things) to start to better unterstand the code. Of course some of these assertions in the beginning will crash. Setting it to -1 in php.ini would work, as then the code is not even parsed.

Comment: It is the use of _assert_options_ which is discouraged, not the use of 'assert.active' and the like. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.assert-options.php

Comment: If the current value is 1, you should be able to set it to 0, but not to -1

Comment: @lukas.j The relationship between assert.active and zend.assertions isn't at all clear in the manual, and I was under the impression - backed up by your testing - that assert.active no longer has any effect. Just to be clear, what actual error do you get if you run `ini_set('zend.assertions', 0)`? If it really is a restriction added by your hosting company, perhaps you should talk to them, since it seems odd to force people to run code in what the manual calls "development mode", and maybe it's just a mistake.

Comment: @IMSoP I get '1' when executing: _echo ini_set('zend.assertions', 0);_. So it does work. The problem is, that a test with _assert(0/0);_ crashes with a DivisionByZeroError, which it should not. I will contact the hosting company. Thank you very much for your help.